# Error: Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException in VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, nunit-3.0, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using using Visual Studio Tests Task for executing NUnit Test cases in VSTS build pipeline.
Below is the configuration setting that i am using:
[Visual Studio Test configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71XIn.png)

[Visual Studio Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzxuX.png)

```
2016-05-09T04:54:10.9189232Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\tasks\VSTest\1.0.34\VSTest.ps1
2016-05-09T04:54:11.8291853Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-VSTest for all test assemblies
2016-05-09T04:54:11.8971852Z Working folder: C:\a\1
2016-05-09T04:54:11.8981845Z Executing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe "C:\a\1\s\Code\DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.CIP.Client.Tests\bin\Release\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.CIP.Client.Tests.dll" "C:\a\1\s\Code\DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.Tests\bin\Release\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.Tests.dll"  /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=Unit" /EnableCodeCoverage /logger:trx /TestAdapterPath:"C:\a\1\s"
2016-05-09T04:54:12.0751854Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.30723.0
2016-05-09T04:54:12.0761850Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2016-05-09T04:54:13.1769952Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2016-05-09T04:54:13.2629955Z Warning: Using Isolation mode to run the tests as diagnostic data adapters were enabled in the runsettings. Use the /inIsolation parameter to suppress this warning.
2016-05-09T04:54:19.9655426Z Information: NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0: Test execution started
2016-05-09T04:54:19.9685422Z Information: Running all tests in C:\a\1\s\Code\DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.CIP.Client.Tests\bin\Release\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.CIP.Client.Tests.dll
2016-05-09T04:54:20.7238005Z Information: NUnit3TestExecutor converted 86 of 86 NUnit test cases
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8381991Z Passed   CIPApiExecutor_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8381991Z Passed   CIPApiExecutor_ConstructNullBaseUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8391998Z Passed   CIPApiExecutor_ExecuteSearchOperationCredentialsMissingPassword
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8391998Z Passed   CIPApiExecutor_ExecuteSearchOperationCredentialsMissingUserName
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8402008Z Passed   CIPRequestBuilder_BuildRequest
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8402008Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_CatalogAliasNotFound
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8402008Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_CatalogNotFound
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8411997Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_LoginFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8411997Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_PasswordExpired
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8421992Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_PermissionDenied
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8421992Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_ServerNotFound
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8431991Z Passed   CIPResponseHandler_UnknownError
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8431991Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_CatalogIsempty
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8431991Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_CatalogIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8441983Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8441983Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_FileNameHasOnlySpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8451986Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_FileNameIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8451986Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_NameHasOnlySpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8451986Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_NameIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8461988Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8461988Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValuesIncludingFile
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8471992Z Passed   AssetImportOperation_StreamIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8471992Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_CatalogIsempty
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8471992Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_CatalogIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8481995Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8481995Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_FileNameHasOnlySpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8481995Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_FileNameIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8491989Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_IDIsNegative
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8491989Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_NameHasOnlySpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8501985Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_NameIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8501985Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8511986Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValuesIncludingFile
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8511986Z Passed   AssetUpdateOperation_StreamIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8511986Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_AssetIdIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8521983Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_AssetIdIsSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8521983Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_CatalogIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8531984Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_CatalogIsSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8531984Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_CategoryIdIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8531984Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_CategoryIdIsSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8541989Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8541989Z Passed   AssignToCategoriesOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8551987Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_CatalogIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8551987Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_CatalogIsSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8551987Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_CategoryIdIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8561985Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_CategoryIdIsSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8561985Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8571990Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_LevelsIsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8571990Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_LevelsIsSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8571990Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8581989Z Passed   GetCategoriesOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValuesWithfield
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8581989Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_CatalogNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8591988Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_CatalogSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8591988Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8591988Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_IdNull
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8601986Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_IdSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8601986Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8611981Z Passed   GetFieldValuesOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValuesAndField
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8611981Z Passed   GetRelatedAssetsOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8611981Z Passed   GetRelatedAssetsOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8621984Z Passed   GetRelatedAssetsOperation_ShouldThrowExceptionAsCatalogIsNotPassed
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8621984Z Passed   GetRelatedAssetsOperation_ShouldThrowExceptionAsRelationIsNotPassed
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8631986Z Passed   GetRelatedAssetsOperation_ShouldUpdateResourceAfterIdChange
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8631986Z Passed   SearchOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:21.8821985Z Information: Running all tests in C:\a\1\s\Code\DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.Tests\bin\Release\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.Tests.dll
2016-05-09T04:54:22.5644196Z Information: NUnit3TestExecutor converted 151 of 151 NUnit test cases
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6494198Z Passed   SearchOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6494198Z Passed   SearchOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValuesAfterAddingParamsManually
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6504200Z Passed   SearchOperation_ShouldThrowExceptionAsCatalogIsNotSet
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6504200Z Passed   SearchOperation_ShouldThrowExceptionAsQuickSearchStringIsNotSet
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6514200Z Passed   SetFieldValuesOperation_CatalogNull
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6514200Z Passed   SetFieldValuesOperation_CatalogSpaces
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6524193Z Passed   SetFieldValuesOperation_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6524193Z Passed   SetFieldValuesOperation_ItemsNull
2016-05-09T04:54:22.6534196Z Passed   SetFieldValuesOperation_ShouldHaveAppropriateValues
2016-05-09T04:54:24.1509203Z Passed   AssetUploadController_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0454861Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UpdateAccountItemIsCurrent
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0454861Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UpdateImageItemIsCurrent
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0474859Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UpdateInvalidAccountItem
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0474859Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UploadAccountIsCurrent
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0484863Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UploadImageItemIsCurrent
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0484863Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UploadInvalidAccountItemAccountItemIsCurrent
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0484863Z Passed   AssetUploadController_UploadInvalidAccountItemImageItemIsCurrent
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0494869Z Passed   CumulusMediaController_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.0494869Z Passed   CumulusMediaController_RenderMedia
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4044863Z Passed   CumulusMediaController_RenderMediaPathShouldBeSet
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4044863Z Passed   CumulusFieldsdataControl_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4054864Z Passed   CumulusFieldsdataControl_DoRenderEmptyValue
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4054864Z Passed   CumulusFieldsdataControl_DoRenderInvalidJsonValue
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4064865Z Passed   CumulusFieldsdataControl_DoRenderJsonValue
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4064865Z Passed   CumulusFieldsdataControl_DoRenderNullValue
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4074867Z Passed   CumulusFieldsdataControl_DoRenderWhitespaceValue
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4074867Z Passed   MediaHandler_AsyncProcessRequestInValidUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4134865Z Passed   MediaHandler_AsyncProcessRequestValidUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4534864Z Passed   MediaHandler_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4544874Z Passed   MediaHandler_GetHttpHandler
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4544874Z Passed   MediaHandler_ProcessRequestInValidUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4544874Z Passed   MediaHandler_ProcessRequestValidUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4554866Z Passed   RegisterMediaRoute_RouteAdded
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4554866Z Passed   CleanupExecutor_AddInvalidTemplate
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4564862Z Passed   CleanupExecutor_AddTemplate
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4564862Z Passed   CleanupExecutor_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.4574855Z Passed   OpenAssetUpdateDialog_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6394863Z Passed   OpenAssetUpdateDialog_DefaultCommandState
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6404868Z Passed   OpenAssetUpdateDialog_Execute
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6404868Z Passed   OpenAssetUpdateDialog_QueryCommandState
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6414868Z Passed   OpenAssetUpdateDialog_QueryCommandStateNonCumulusMediaItem
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6414868Z Passed   OpenAssetUploadDialog_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6424869Z Passed   OpenAssetUploadDialog_DefaultCommandState
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6424869Z Passed   OpenAssetUploadDialog_Execute
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6434865Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetCategories
2016-05-09T04:54:25.6434865Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetCategoriesMultiLevel
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8404864Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetCategoryIds
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8414862Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetCategoryIdsMultiLevel
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8414862Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetFields10Fields
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8424869Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetFieldsNoCustomFields
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8424869Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetWidthHeight
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8424869Z Passed   AccountHelper_GetWidthHeightNoSettings
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8434865Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetAssetFromNonMediaSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8434865Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetExcelAssetFromSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:25.8444858Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetImageAssetFromSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1204869Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetPDFAssetFromSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1204869Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetPPTAssetFromSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1214864Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetVideoAssetFromSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1214864Z Passed   AssetHelper_GetWordAssetFromSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1224865Z Passed   AssetHelper_PopulateSitecoreItem
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1224865Z Passed   AssetHelper_StaticConstruct
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1234867Z Passed   CategoryImportExecutor_GetCategories
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1234867Z Passed   CategoryImportExecutor_GetDataNoCatalog
2016-05-09T04:54:26.1234867Z Passed   CategoryImportExecutor_GetDataNoCIPUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4874863Z Passed   CategoryImportExecutor_GetDataNoPassword
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4884866Z Passed   CategoryImportExecutor_GetDataNoUsername
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4884866Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetCategoriesQueryString
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4904864Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetCategoriesQueryStringAllSubCategories
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4904864Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetCategoriesQueryStringDefinedSubCategories
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4914860Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetData
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4914860Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataAdditionalFields
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4924853Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataAdditionalFieldsIncludesInvalidField
2016-05-09T04:54:26.4924853Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataInvalidCredentials
2016-05-09T04:54:26.5984864Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataNoCatalog
2016-05-09T04:54:26.5984864Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataNoCIPUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:26.5994866Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataNoImageFactoryUrl
2016-05-09T04:54:26.5994866Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataNoPassword
2016-05-09T04:54:26.6004863Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataNoSettings
2016-05-09T04:54:26.6004863Z Passed   ImportExecutor_GetDataNoUsername
2016-05-09T04:54:26.6004863Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_CategoryDataInvalidType
2016-05-09T04:54:26.6014858Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_CategoryDataNotSet
2016-05-09T04:54:26.6014858Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_CategoryNoMediaContentFolder
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7484855Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7494856Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_NonCumulusAccount
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7494856Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_ProcessNoneDeleted
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7504851Z Passed   CategoryCleanup_ProcessOneDeleted
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7504851Z Passed   GetCategories_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7504851Z Passed   GetCategories_NonCumulusAccount
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7514851Z Passed   GetCategories_Process
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7514851Z Passed   GetCategories_ProcessGetCategoriesAlreadySet
2016-05-09T04:54:26.7524860Z Passed   GetCategories_ProcessGetCategoriesFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8334868Z Passed   GetCategories_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8344917Z Passed   GetCategories_NonCumulusAccount
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8344917Z Passed   GetCategories_Process
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8354881Z Passed   GetCategories_ProcessGetCategoriesAlreadySet
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8354881Z Passed   GetCategories_ProcessGetCategoriesFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8364885Z Passed   SetCategoryPathForAsset_CategoriesDataInvalidType
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8364885Z Passed   SetCategoryPathForAsset_CategoriesDataNotSet
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8374884Z Passed   SetCategoryPathForAsset_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:26.8374884Z Passed   SetCategoryPathForAsset_NonCumulusAccount
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0594862Z Passed   SetCategoryPathForAsset_NoResultData
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0594862Z Passed   SetCategoryPathForAsset_Process
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0604862Z Passed   CreateCategoryFolder_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0604862Z Passed   CreateCategoryFolder_NonCumulusAccount
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0614862Z Passed   CreateCategoryFolder_ProcessCreateAllCategories
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0614862Z Passed   CreateCategoryFolder_ProcessCreateCumulusCategories
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0624861Z Passed   UpdateCategoryFolder_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0624861Z Passed   UpdateCategoryFolder_MoveItem
2016-05-09T04:54:27.0634853Z Passed   UpdateCategoryFolder_MoveItemCategoryNotFound
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2384854Z Passed   UpdateCategoryFolder_MoveItemMultipleCategory
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2394849Z Passed   UpdateCategoryFolder_NonCumulusAccount
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2394849Z Passed   UpdateCategoryFolder_ProcessSameCategory
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2404847Z Passed   ImagePlayerMarkupGenerator_Generate
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2404847Z Passed   ImagePlayerMarkupGenerator_GetDefaultPlayer
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2404847Z Passed   ImagePlayerMarkupGenerator_GetMediaId
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2414851Z Passed   ImagePlayerMarkupGenerator_GetPreviewImage
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2414851Z Passed   OfficeFilePlayerMarkupGenerator_Generate
2016-05-09T04:54:27.2424854Z Passed   OfficeFilePlayerMarkupGenerator_GetDefaultPlayer
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4034860Z Passed   OfficeFilePlayerMarkupGenerator_GetMediaId
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4034860Z Passed   OfficeFilePlayerMarkupGenerator_GetPreviewImage
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4044862Z Passed   PDFPlayerMarkupGenerator_Generate
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4044862Z Passed   PDFPlayerMarkupGenerator_GetDefaultPlayer
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4054858Z Passed   PDFPlayerMarkupGenerator_GetMediaId
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4054858Z Passed   PDFPlayerMarkupGenerator_GetPreviewImage
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4064858Z Passed   VideoPlayerMarkupGenerator_Generate
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4064858Z Passed   VideoPlayerMarkupGenerator_GetDefaultPlayer
2016-05-09T04:54:27.4064858Z Passed   VideoPlayerMarkupGenerator_GetMediaId
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5024859Z Passed   VideoPlayerMarkupGenerator_GetPreviewImage
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5024859Z Passed   EntityCreator_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5034868Z Passed   EntityCreator_CreateEntity
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5034868Z Passed   Synchronizer_CheckMappedTemplatesList
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5044857Z Passed   Synchronizer_FalseNeedUpdate
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5044857Z Passed   Synchronizer_GetMediaData_AllInputsProvided
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5054866Z Passed   Synchronizer_GetMediaData_NonCumulusMediaEntity
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5054866Z Passed   Synchronizer_GetMediaData_TitleNotProvided
2016-05-09T04:54:27.5054866Z Passed   Synchronizer_GetRootItemMediaContent
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0434859Z Passed   StreamingUploadProvider_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0434859Z Passed   StreamingUploadProvider_UploadAccountEmpty
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0444865Z Passed   StreamingUploadProvider_UploadAccountNotDefined
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0444865Z Passed   StreamingUploadProvider_UploadFile
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0454862Z Passed   StreamingUploadProvider_UploadNoFiles
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0454862Z Passed   UploadExecutor_Construct
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0454862Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadBytes
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0464864Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadStream
2016-05-09T04:54:28.0464864Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadStreamAccountItemNull
2016-05-09T04:54:28.3974918Z Information: NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0: Test execution complete
2016-05-09T04:54:28.4044854Z Information: NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
2016-05-09T04:54:28.5384864Z ##[error]Error: Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests in C:\a\1\s\Code\DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.CIP.Client.Tests\bin\Release\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.CIP.Client.Tests.dll
2016-05-09T04:54:28.5394864Z ##[error]
2016-05-09T04:54:28.8464860Z ##[error]Error: Exception NUnit.Core.UnsupportedFrameworkException, Exception thrown executing tests in C:\a\1\s\Code\DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.Tests\bin\Release\Honeywell.ACS.EP.DAM.Tests.dll
2016-05-09T04:54:28.8474860Z ##[error]
2016-05-09T04:54:28.8474860Z Information: NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9624859Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadStreamAssetImportFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9624859Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadStreamAssignToCategoriesFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9634856Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadStreamGetAssetFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9634856Z Passed   UploadExecutor_UploadStreamValidationFailed
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9644858Z Passed   CumulusField_Equals
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9644858Z Passed   CumulusField_EqualsNotMatch
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9644858Z Passed   CumulusField_EqualsTypesDifferent
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9654861Z Passed   CumulusField_GetHashCode
2016-05-09T04:54:28.9654861Z Passed   CumulusField_GetHashCodeNotSame
2016-05-09T04:54:29.1998707Z Results File: C:\a\1\TestResults\buildguest_TASKAGENT5-0004 2016-05-09 04_54_21.trx
2016-05-09T04:54:29.2028714Z Attachments:
2016-05-09T04:54:29.2028714Z ##[error]Test Run Failed.
2016-05-09T04:54:29.2038710Z   C:\a\1\TestResults\8f7b9606-3cb8-4fdc-9bed-38d7f3d33941\buildguest_TASKAGENT5-0004 2016-05-09 04_54_17.coverage
2016-05-09T04:54:29.2038710Z Total tests: 217. Passed: 217. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2016-05-09T04:54:29.2048713Z Test execution time: 9.5203 Seconds
2016-05-09T04:54:29.2981743Z ##[error]VSTest Test Run failed with exit code: 1
2016-05-09T04:54:29.3501771Z Publishing Test Results...
2016-05-09T04:54:30.2816813Z Test results remaining: 217
2016-05-09T04:54:31.4568803Z Published Test Run :
```

I have already tried the solution given in the post:
[VSTS Build fails running NUnit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360270/vsts-build-fails-running-nunit-tests)

Answer (score 7):

You are using NUnit Test Adapter 2.0 to run NUnit Test 3.0 what will cause the error.

Install [NUnit3TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/3.0.10) to your project and specify it as the test adapter should fix your issue.

Comment: Looking at the log - it looks to me like you actually have both the NUnit3 AND NUnit 2 adapters running. The NUnit 2 adapter (just called "NUnit VS Adapter") is throwing the exception, presumably because your test suite is  NUnit3. Uninstalling that one should help.

Comment: I am using NUnit test Adapter 3.0 only, 2.0 is not installed

Comment: @RaviGupta According to the logs, 2.0 is involved during the testing. You may need to check if it exists in your source folder.

Comment: @Eddie I checked the source folder there were no reference to NUnit 2.0

Comment: @RaviGupta Then do you have nuget packages installed for NUnit 2.0?

Comment: I've installed NUnit test Adapter 3.0 nuget only

Comment: @RaviGupta, did you solve it? I have the same problem, and no reference to 2.0 that I can find

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when running with self-hosted vsts agent. The problem appeared right after migrating to NUnit3. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41630673/6339675). Indeed, the NUnit2 packages were being cached by the agent. The problem disappeared after deleting the `_work` and `_diag` directories and restarting the agent.

Comment: deleting directories from where?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Nuget Packages are named very poorly.  Go through each NUnit-related package in your project and ***read the description*** - some will actually be legacy V2-based packages even though they have a 3.x "version" to them.